# Target all adjacent siblings of an element in a nested list with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is simplified markup that I have on my site:

```
<div id="block">
    <ol>
        <li> <--
            <ol>
                <li>
                    ...
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li> <--
    </ol>       
    <ol>
        <li> <--
            <ol>
                <li>
                    ...
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li> <--
    </ol>
</div>
```

I want to target only the first level `li` elements in each each top-level `ol` (I mark them with arrows).

How should I write my selectors to target these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) to target children only

```
#block > ol > li { … }
```

This automatically excludes [descendant](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) `li` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this

```
#block > ol > li
```

Using the > will make sure it's 1 level deeper, not more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the child combinator selector, but you need to be careful because some CSS properties are inherited.

For example, the `list-style` property will apply to the first `li` only because of the selectors.  However, the `color` property will be inherited.

You may need to reset some properties back to some default value as needed using a reset rule.

```css
#block > ol > li {
  color: blue;
  list-style: circle;
}
#block > ol > li * {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <ol>
        <li> <--
            <ol>
                <li>
                    ...test
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li> <--
    </ol>       
    <ol>
        <li> <--
            <ol>
                <li>
                    ...test
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li> <--
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#block ul > li {}
```

For more information see https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/